# Neo4j / Cypher: Returning sum of value in relationship between nodes within the node itself

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There are two node types, `Account` and `Transfer`. A `Transfer` signifies movement of funds between `Account` nodes. `Transfer` nodes may have any number of input and output nodes. For example, three `Accounts` could each send $40 ($120 combined) to sixteen other `Accounts` in any way they please and it would work.

The `Transfer` object, as is, does not have the sum of the funds sent or received - those are only stored in the relationships themselves. I'd like to calculate this in the cypher query and return it as part of the the returned `Transfer` object, **not separately**. (Similar to a SQL JOIN)

I'm rather new to Neo4j + Cypher; So far, the query I've got is this:

```
MATCH (tf:Transfer {id:'some_id'})
MATCH (tf)<-[in:IN_TO]-(in_account:Account)
MATCH (tf)-[out:OUT_TO]->(out_account:Account)
RETURN tf,in_account,in,out_account,out, sum(in.value) as sum_in, sum(out.value) as sum_out
```

If I managed this database, I'd just precalculate the sums and store it in the `Transfer` properties - but that's not an option at this time.

**tl;dr:** I'd like to store `sum_in` and `sum_out` in the returned `tf` object.

Answer (score 0):

When you use an aggregation like `SUM`, you have to leave the aggregated aliases out of your result row, or you'll end up with single-row sums. This should help you get something closer to what you want, including a workaround for your dynamic property assignment:

```
CREATE (temp)
WITH temp
MATCH (tf:Transfer {id:'some_id'})
MATCH (tf)<-[in:IN_TO]-(in_account:Account)
MATCH (tf)-[out:OUT_TO]->(out_account:Account)
SET temp += PROPERTIES(tf)
WITH temp, SUM(in.value) AS sum_in, SUM(out.value) AS sum_out, COLLECT(in_account) AS in_accounts, COLLECT(out_account) AS out_accounts 
SET temp.sum_in = sum_in
SET temp.sum_out = sum_out
WITH temp, PROPERTIES(temp) AS props, in_accounts, out_accounts
DELETE temp
RETURN props, in_accounts, out_accounts
```

You are creating a dummy node to hold properties, because that's the only way to assign dynamic properties to existing Maps or Map-alikes, but the node won't ever be committed to the graph. This query should return a Map of the `:Transfer`'s properties, with the in- and out-sums included, plus lists of the in- and out-accounts in case you need to do any additional work on them.

Comment: h/t to Gábor for the typo catch.

Answer (score 0):

Tore Eschliman's answer is very insightful, especially on the properties of aggregated aliases.

I came up with a more hackish solution, that could work in this case.

Example data set:

```
CREATE
  (a1:Account),
  (a2:Account),
  (a3:Account),
  (tf:Transfer),
  (a1)-[:IN_TO {value: 110}]->(tf),
  (a2)-[:IN_TO {value: 230}]->(tf),
  (tf)-[:OUT_TO {value: 450}]->(a3)
```

Query:

```
MATCH (in_account:Account)-[in:IN_TO]->(tf:Transfer)
WITH tf, SUM(in.value) AS sum_in
SET tf.sum_in = sum_in
RETURN tf
UNION
MATCH (tf:Transfer)-[out:OUT_TO]->(out_account:Account)
WITH tf, SUM(out.value) AS sum_out
SET tf.sum_out = sum_out
RETURN tf
```

Results:

```
╒═══════════════════════════╕
│tf                         │
╞═══════════════════════════╡
│{sum_in: 340, sum_out: 450}│
└───────────────────────────┘
```

Note that `UNION` performs a set union (as opposed to `UNION ALL`, which performs a multiset/bag union), hence we will not have duplicates in the results.

*Update:* as Tore Eschliman pointed out in the comments, this solution will modify the database. As a workaround, you can collect the results and abort the transaction afterwards.

Comment: Good point. I tried to fix it, but it seems this is not a good direction for solving the problem. I am very interested now in a solution, but I couldn't get your query working with the example data set: if you use `DELETE temp`, the result row will be full of empty values and collections of empty values. If you remove `DELETE temp`, it works like a charm. (I am using Neo4j 3.0.4.)

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I forgot the most important part. You have to assign `PROPERTIES(n)` to another alias before you delete or it will disappear.